# Java Unable to Call Method from HashMap

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, hashmap

I am trying to increment the observations field in the Bird class. I have tried a few different ways, but I can't seem to get it to increment. Essentially, I want to call the addObservations() to add an observation to the count in the event the bird is already found in the Map. The issue clearly lies in the observe() in BirdData. Below is the code

```
    public class Bird {
        private String name;
        private String latinName;
        private int year;
        private int observations;


    public Bird (String name, String latinName, int year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latinName = latinName;
        this.year = year;
        this.observations = 0;

    }

    public int getObservations() {
        return this.observations;
    }

    public void addObservation() {
        observations++;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getLatinName() {
            return this.latinName;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        } if (this.getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        } 

        Bird compared = (Bird) o;
        if (this.latinName == null || !this.latinName.equals(compared.latinName)){
         return false;   
        } if (this.year != compared.year) {
            return false;
        }



        return true;

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            if (this.latinName == null) {
                return 11;
            }


            return this.year +this.latinName.hashCode();


        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name + ", " +this.latinName + ": " + this.year + " " +this.observations;
        }

        }

public class BirdData {


    private Map<Bird, String> birdList;
    private Bird bird;


    public BirdData() {
        this.birdList = new HashMap<Bird, String>();
}


    public void observe (Bird bird, String place) {

        for (Bird b : birdList.keySet()) {
            if (birdList.get(b).equals(bird)){
                b.addObservation();
            }

        } if (!birdList.containsKey(bird)){
                birdList.put(bird, place);

                }

}

    public void observations (Bird bird) {

        if (birdList.containsKey(bird)) {
            System.out.println(bird + " observations: " + bird.getObservations());
        }

    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        BirdData bl = new BirdData();



        bl.observe(new Bird ("Rose Starling", "Sturnus roseus", 2012), "Arabia");
        bl.observe(new Bird ("Rose Starling", "Sturnus roseus", 2012), "Arabia");
        bl.observe(new Bird ("Rose Starling", "Sturnus roseus", 2012), "Arabia");
        bl.observe(new Bird ("Rose Starling", "Sturnus roseus", 2018), "Arabia");

        bl.observations(new Bird ("Rose Starling", "Sturnus roseus", 2012));
        bl.observations(new Bird ("Rose Starling", "Sturnus roseus", 2018));







    }


}
```

Comment: Whats the point of using a hashmap if you are just iterating over all the keys?

Comment: The most common cause for this sort of thing, [IME](http://www.abbreviations.com/term/118), is that `equals` and `hashcode` aren't properly implemented and don't agree, so you don't match the object you're looking for — but luckydog32 is also right, and you may just be going about this the wrong way altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As assumed, the error is located in `BirdData.observe()`. In particular it's a false condition:

`birdList.get(b)` will return a `String` and is compared to `bird` which is a `Bird`. In consequence, `b.addObservation()` will never be executed.

---

As I'm not exactly familiar with the expected logic of your program I can only give hints on how to solve this. Please take in mind to choose carefully, which of the following will fit your requirements:

```
public void observe (Bird bird, String place) {
    bird.addObservation();
}
```

This ignores the `place` parameter, but some other comments already pointed out, that the `place` info itself isn't used too much anyway. Maybe it's not intended to be used here.

**OR**

replace

```
if (birdList.get(b).equals(bird)){
```

with

```
if (bird.equals(b) && birdList.containsKey(b) && birdList.get(b).equals(place)){
```

*(You can obviously save the `birdList.containsKey()`, if you place the `for` loop in an `else` condition on the following `if` condition.)*

This considers both `bird` and `place`.

Comment: What would be the proper way to compare the two objects then? I thought .equals would work for this type of scenario. I also tested .containsKey, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

`if (birdList.get(b).equals(bird)){`

with

`if (birdList.get(b).equals(place)){`

Basically, you should add the bird to the observed list only if both the supplied parameters - bird and place are found in the map as a key value pair.

By the way, you can do it in a much quicker (less code) way:

```
if(place.equals(birdList.get(bird)) {
     b.addObservation();
}
else {
     birdList.put(bird, place);
}
```

Comment: I just tried both of these solutions; neither of them seem to increment the value. The first one leaves it as is, while the second actually fails to put the bird into the hashmap causing the program to contain no ouput.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are restricting your bird sightings to only one location by using a `HashMap<Bird, String>`. I think it would be more useful to allow for multiple locations to be stored for each bird by saving the locations in a `HashSet<String>` inside the bird object.

If you want to use a HashMap to search for `Bird` objects at that point it gets a little tricky, but you can use the `Bird` object as both the key and value in the HashMap.

So in the `Bird` Object, add this:

```
HashSet<String> locations;
```

And then for observing you can do something like this:

```
Map<Bird, Bird> birdList = new HashMap<>();

public void observe (Bird bird, String place) {

    Bird retreivedBird = birdList.get(bird);

    if(retreivedBird != null){
        if(!retreivedBird.locations.contains(place)){
            retreivedBird.locations.add(place);
        }
    }else{
        retreivedBird = bird;
        bird.locations.add(place);
        birdList.put(bird, bird);
    }
    retreivedBird.addObservation();
}
```

Comment: I have actually tried a similar approach the other day and received an incompatible type error in the "Bird retreivedBird = birdList.get(bird);" part. I think, judging from your previous comment as well, that I need to approach this differently since the HashMap is just not working in this situation.

Comment: @Dyeh oh I forgot to include the HashMap initialization, I was using `HashMap<Bird, Bird>` not `HashMap<Bird, String>`

Comment: @Dyeh310 Added it in now, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all of the help. None of the recommended solutions actually incremented the observation field as need. I ended up rebuilding the BirdData section, creating a HashMap containing Bird and a List. Then to keep count of the observations, I used birdList.size();. This removed the field from Bird entirely solving the issue. Thanks for the feedback.